# Varnish Daemon does not start: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: c, compiler-construction, cygwin, vcl, varnish

I try to setup varnish on my local development system but it terminates seconds after the start with these messages:

```
varnishd -s malloc,1G -T 127.0.0.1:2000 -a 0.0.0.0:81 -F -f /etc/default.vcl

0 [main] collect2 9660 fork: child -1 - died waiting for longjmp before initialization, retry 10, exit code 0xC0000135, errno 11
1044289 [main] collect2 9660 fork: child -1 - died waiting for longjmp before initialization, retry 10, exit code 0xC0000135, errno 11
3081454 [main] collect2 9660 fork: child -1 - died waiting for longjmp before initialization, retry 10, exit code 0xC0000135, errno 11
7205979 [main] collect2 9660 fork: child -1 - died waiting for longjmp before initialization, retry 10, exit code 0xC0000135, errno 11
Message from C-compiler:
collect2: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
0 [main] collect2 9660 fork: child -1 - died waiting for longjmp before initialization, retry 10, exit code 0xC0000135, errno 11
1044289 [main] collect2 9660 fork: child -1 - died waiting for longjmp before initialization, retry 10, exit code 0xC0000135, errno 11
3081454 [main] collect2 9660 fork: child -1 - died waiting for longjmp before initialization, retry 10, exit code 0xC0000135, errno 11
7205979 [main] collect2 9660 fork: child -1 - died waiting for longjmp before initialization, retry 10, exit code 0xC0000135, errno 11
Running C-compiler failed, exit 1

VCL compilation failed
```

Google didn't help a lot, does anyone have an idea what is going wrong and how i could solve that issue?

Ok started a bounty now. Some more infos: The dev system uses Windows, but runnning cygwin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many forking issues in cygwin can be solved by re-basing the cygwin DLLs.

First, make sure the `dash` and `rebase` packages are installed via cygwin setup. 
Close all cygwin windows and processes (including X11, etc.) 
Then, from a command prompt (Start menu -> run -> cmd), execute `c:\pathtocygwin\dash.exe -c '/usr/bin/rebaseall'`

See more information in the wiki here: http://cygwin.wikia.com/wiki/Rebaseall